# Programming with Class Definition

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is the question below for everyone to have a better understanding:

Write a class definition for the Person class and write user-defined functions with these function headers:

```
def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
  # Return a a new person object with the given name, height and birthdate.
  # - name is a str
  # - height is an int object in centimetres
  # - birthdate is a date object from the
  # module datetime
```

---

```
def get_age(person):
  # Return the age of the person in years.
```

For example, assume today's date is June 12, 2018. if Mary was born on June 4, 2017, then Mary's age is 1. However, if Bob was born on June 14, 2018, then Bob would not have had a first birthday yet so the age is 0.

```
def get_description(person):
# Return a string object of the form: Name is
# N cm high and is M years old, where N and M
# are integers
```

For example, Michael is 190 cm high and is 43 years old or Samantha is 95 cm high and is 4 years old.

```
def main():
# Create a person named 'Michael', with height
# 190 cm, who was born on August 14, 1976 and
# output a description of this individual.
```

If you use a function from an imported module when writing your function, you usually declare the import statement at the top of your code.

Here is a sample run of a main program that just calls the main function.

```
Michael is 190 cm high and is 43 years old.
```

Hint:

Use the date class from the datetime module to represent a date. An object whose type is date, has attributes: year, month and day that you can use to compute the age of a Person.

To compute the current age of a person, you will need to first compute today's date. There is a method in the date class of the datetime module that creates a new date object that represents the current date. The name of this method is today. However, the special argument of this method must be the date class itself, instead of a particular object whose type is date. A method that is applied to a class object instead of to an instance of that class is called a class method.

Therefore, to create the current date you can use the expression:

date.today()

since after importing the date class from the datetime module, the identifier date is bound to the date class object.

To compute the age you can just subtract the year attribute of the birthdate from the year attribute of the current date. However, you will also need to check whether the person has already had their birthday yet this year and if not, subtract one year

---

This is the code I have so far, I'm getting an error

`RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 27:`
`print(get_description(person)))`
`RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 22:`
`return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old.'`
`AttributeError: type object 'person' has no attribute 'name'`

The expected answer is suppose to be

```
Michael is 190 cm high and is 43 years old.
```

Can someone help me please?Thank you

---

```
from datetime import date

class person:
  pass

def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
  name = 'Michael'
  height = 190
  birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
  return person
  
def get_age(person):
  birthdate = person.birth
  today = date.today()
  subyear = 0
  if today.month < birthdate.month or (today.month == birthdate.day and today.day <= birthdate.day):
    subyear = 1
  person.age = (today.year - (birthdate.year + subyear))
  return person.age

def get_description(person):
  return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old.'

def main():
  birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
  person = create_person('Michael', 190, birthdate)
  print(get_description(person))
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code review site.

Comment: @MattDMo okay thank you. I edited my post

Comment: I doubt your assignment has to work with Python 2; you can remove that tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a person object before setting the properties:

```
def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
  p = person()
  p.name = 'Michael'
  p.height = 190
  p.birthdate = date(1976, 8, 14)
  return p
```

Even better, you should use the parameters:

```
def create_person(name, height, birthdate):
  p = person()
  p.name = name
  p.height = height
  p.birthdate = birthdate
  return p
```

Comment: I think it works but now I'm getting an error: `RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 28:` / `print(get_description(person)))` `RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 23:` / `return person.name + ' is ' + str(person.height) + ' cm high and is ' + str(get_age(person)) + ' years old.')`
/ `RuntimeErrorElement(RuntimeError,Error on line 14:` `birthdate = person.birth
AttributeError: 'person' object has no attribute 'birth'`

Comment: The property is `birthdate`, not `birth`

Comment: I didn't notice that. Thank you very much. It worked with the 2nd parameters because the system used a different input named "Sara". Thank you again for your assistance. You're a boss!